# Wifi Adapter not found on Debian

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, debian

I'm running Debian 11 with kernel 5.10.0-17-amd64.
My laptop is a Lenovo ThinkPad P14s Gen 2 (21A0004TFR).

I haven't been able to make the wifi work so far (ethernet works fine).

Here are some command outputs of things I started investigating:

```
> inxi -Fxz
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000 
           bus ID: 02:00.0 
           IF: enp2s0f0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: MEDIATEK vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A port: 3000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
           Device-3: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 2000 
           bus ID: 05:00.0 
           IF: enp5s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-1: br-605c2ef5c4bc state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-2: br-a8fc9d04dbe0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-3: docker0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-4: tailscale0 state: unknown speed: -1 duplex: full mac: N/A 
           IF-ID-5: veth02f0187 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-6: veth071f1d4 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-7: veth1bab723 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-8: veth2204db2 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-9: veth24f9839 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-10: veth25d325e state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-11: veth274fe7f state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-12: veth394ac69 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-13: veth4f2a87a state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-14: veth61c9792 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-15: veth63dbd09 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-16: veth6913750 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-17: veth7a779b2 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-18: veth7b65fd0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-19: veth7c6c330 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-20: veth8c9d870 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-21: veth8dc51db state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-22: veth8efa502 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-23: vetha5b006d state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-24: vethd6d85d8 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-25: vethdc2462e state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
```

```
> sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0f0  no wireless extensions.

enp5s0    no wireless extensions.

tailscale0  no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

br-605c2ef5c4bc  no wireless extensions.

br-a8fc9d04dbe0  no wireless extensions.

veth24f9839  no wireless extensions.

veth63dbd09  no wireless extensions.

veth61c9792  no wireless extensions.

veth8dc51db  no wireless extensions.

vethdc2462e  no wireless extensions.

veth25d325e  no wireless extensions.

veth8c9d870  no wireless extensions.

veth6913750  no wireless extensions.

veth274fe7f  no wireless extensions.

veth394ac69  no wireless extensions.

veth2204db2  no wireless extensions.

vetha5b006d  no wireless extensions.

veth02f0187  no wireless extensions.

veth7a779b2  no wireless extensions.

veth8efa502  no wireless extensions.

vethd6d85d8  no wireless extensions.

veth1bab723  no wireless extensions.

veth7b65fd0  no wireless extensions.

veth7c6c330  no wireless extensions.

veth4f2a87a  no wireless extensions.

veth071f1d4  no wireless extensions.
```

```
> sudo rfkill list all
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
> lsusb
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0489:e0cd Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. Prometheus MIS Touch Fingerprint Reader
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b724 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
> lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.6 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.7 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166a
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166b
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166c
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166d
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166e
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166f
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1670
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1671
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Device 174a
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7961
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
06:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 02)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne (rev d1)
07:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
07:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
07:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
07:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
07:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
07:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

dmesg gives me this: https://pastebin.com/eLQcEcHb

I have no clue where to go next

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340800/wifi-not-working-on-asus-rog-zephyrus-g14-2021 you should try and install from bullseye-backports a newer kernel and newer firmwares and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Likely, you nee to install the Debian driver for the Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 adapter. Linux drivers are available [at Realtek](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software), and I've had good results with [these from GitHub](https://github.com/airium/Realtek-PCIe-GBE-NIC-Driver), which also explains how to build it.

You also should look at [UnixBlogger](https://unixblogger.wordpress.com/2016/08/11/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/), *How To get your Realtek RTL8111/RTL8168 working,* for more on driver installation.

Please let us know if this resolves the issue.

Comment: Are those the drivers for Ethernet? My Ethernet works fine though, it's only the WiFi